# Order of congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have a theorem saying that if a<sup>r</sup> ≡ a<sup>s</sup>modp, then the order e of a has e|(s-r). Is this correct? Can you then also conclude that the order e|(r-s)? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is $\, e\,$?

Comment: Sorry, e is the order of a?

Comment: Yes, the theorem is correct. What do you mean "Can you then also conclude that the order e|(r-s)?" That is the theorem. It is still true, so I am not sure what you are asking. That is the same conclusion as what the theorem states.

Comment: Thanks! So the order of the 's' and the 't' doesn't matter then?

Comment: I see what you are asking. I apologize. Yes, it is true because congruence is an equivalence relation. If $a^r \equiv a^s \pmod{p}$ then $a^s \equiv a^r\pmod{p}$ is also true by symmetry, and then just apply the same theorem.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!!

Comment: Note:  $e$ is a poor choice of variable here...in a group theory context, $e$ denotes the identity element.  That said, your claim is perfectly true.